# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_events"

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a bit of a quirky case. I'm not sure if this is a Rails bug (I'm using version 4.1.4). Perhaps, I need to upgrade my version.

Essentially:

My `Event` model has the following association:

```
has_many :attendees, -> { order(:name).select('users.*, user_events.event_title') },
through: :user_events,
source: :user
```

What this does is get me Users that attend an event and via the `user_events` join table, it'll also get me their `event_title`.

This works in simple cases: `event.attendees`

However, it errors out in the following:

`Event.includes(:attendees).where.not(title: "wow")`

The problem is basically that `user_events` is not added to the FROM clause in the command that errors out. It is added in `event.attendees` though.

How would I get it to properly be added?

I've tried `Event.includes(:attendees).joins(:user_events).where.not(title: "wow")` but it adds `user_events` to the wrong SQL call.

Answer (score 0):

What i got over here that you need those whose title is not 'wow' by above query? Correct.
If this is then you should use references method over there as rails don't understand title is on "user_events" tables, because you called it from Event also you can write it like this

> Event.includes(:attendees).joins(:user_events).where.not(user_events:
>   {title: "wow"})